# 現在のページと関係ないprepopが呼び出される

Tags: onsen-ui

CordovaとOnsen UIでアプリを開発しています。

親画面→詳細画面→子画面の構造になっており、詳細画面→親画面へ戻る場合のみに以下の処理を行いたいのですが、どのように実装すればよいでしょうか。
以下のコードは詳細画面のcontroller内に記載しています。

```
myNavigator.on('prepop', function(event) {
    $interval.cancel(promise);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.currentPage`で現在のページオブジェクトが取得できますので下記のように`name`プロパティで分岐させてはいかがでしょうか。

```
myNavigator.on('prepop', function(event) {
    if (event.currentPage.name === 'hoge') {
        $interval.cancel(promise);
    }
});
```

https://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html#event-prepop